# Heat Pump Compressor not turning on in heat mode

Tags: heating, fans, heat-pump, compressor, blower

### UPDATE 29-MAY-2021:

So I have it working now, after playing around with some of the settings in both the Nest Thermostat and the Zone Control Panel. In the "Pro Setup" section of the Nest, I adjusted the "Heat Pump Orientation" to "B". On the Zone Control board, there is a dip switch you can set to 'O' or 'B' - From the instructions for the zone panel: *"When using Heat Pump type thermostats this determines if the O or B terminal is wired to the W/OB terminal on each thermostat to determine if the call is for Heat (B) or Cool (O)."*

Now that it's operating as expected, my thinking is:

On a call for cooling from the thermostat, the thermostats (through the zone panel) will energize Y (compressor) and O (reversing valve), along with G for fan.

On a call for heating from the thermostat, the thermostats will energize Y and the W1/B terminal, along with G for fan. The O terminal will not be energized.

I originally had the "Heat Pump Orientation" in the Nest  and zone panel set to 'O', thinking that the the O would be energized during a heat call.

I don't think I fully understand the logic here, so I'm going to keep this question open if someone can explain it?

### Original Question:

I have a Goodman GSZC heat pump paired with an AVPTC air handler. My house is zone controlled with a ZoneFirst H32P control board. I have 3 nest thermostats for each of the zones.

On calls for cooling, everything works fine, outdoor compressor kicks on and blower in attic turns on, cold air is delivered to the house. However when I change to heating mode, the compressor outside does not kick in, and the blower just runs in constant fan mode.

Any suggestions on where to start for troubleshooting this?

Zone panel - W1/B terminal on HVAC output goes to O terminal on outdoor unit, all other wires go to air handler control board.

[image]

Nest wiring - Rh and W2/AUX go to oil fired boiler for hot water baseboard (dual fuel setup)

[image]

Outdoor unit wiring - O terminal connects directly to zone panel, all other wires go to air handler control board.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with wiring diagrams for both the outdoor and indoor units please?

Comment: Is this a new problem or new thermostats? Are all 3 thermostats changed to heat mode? How long did you wait once the call for heat was made?

Comment: What is the outdoor temperature. There should be a thermostat that switches to auxiliary heat when it gets below a given temperature (wide range on this setting), is it calling for Auxiliary heat or the heat pump. You may have an emergency heat switch that will turn on an auxiliary heat source or try to turn on a non existent one.

Comment: It’s a brand new install, so my suspicion is I have the the O/B wiring between thermostats, zone board and outdoor unit messed up somewhere. I’ll edit the post in a bit with some pictures. Temp outside is 45 so it’s not kicking on aux heat (lockout temp setting is 35)